# Is the verb umfassen separable?

Tags: separable-verb

I just read the following sentence in a document at my office:

> Das Listing umfasst pro Artikel folgende Informationen:

Is this correct? Wouldn't it be better this?

> Das Listing fasst pro Artikel folgende Informationen um:

[This](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=umfassen&dispatch=inflection&features=(Cat%20V)&service=canooNet) page makes me confused, on the topic. It seems like in some cases is separable, and in some other is not:

Comment: Nope, *umfassen* is not separable.

Comment: I have updated the question, on more details about my confusion

Comment: That’s interesting, I am really pressured to find an example of a separable *umfassen* atm …

Comment: See also Duden entry for [_umfassen_](http://www.duden.de/node/765333/revisions/1366212/view), which is not to be confused with the separable verb [_umfassen_](http://www.duden.de/node/817045/revisions/1376792/view).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, in this context (the listing) it is not seperable.

Note: in the context of grip (e.g. in climbing) *umfassen* is seperable, see https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/umfassen

**Edit:**

As user unknown pointed out: if *umfassen* is used to describe an activity then it’s seperable.

1. *etwas anders anfassen:*

   > Er fasste um, da seine Hand begann weh zu tun.
   > He had to change grip as his hand began to hurt.
2. *etwas umfassen (lassen):*

   > Der Juwelier fasste den Juwel um. [(see also Part B)](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=23,872,73)
   > The jeweller changed the setting of the jewel

In my experience the seperable form of *umfassen* is rather rare used for daily use. Especially the #2 from above since it’s only valid in the context of jewellery.

If *umfassen* is used to describe a state (e.g. to list something) then it is not seperaple:

- > Sein Aufgabenbereich umfasst unter anderem (…)
  > Its remit includes the following (…)
- > Diese umfassen die Prinzipien der Charta der Grundrechte der Europäischen Union, den Schutz der menschlichen Würde und (…)
  > These include the principles reflected in the Charter of Fundamental Rights of the European Union, protection of human dignity and (…)
- > Zahlreiche Gärten umfassen das Schloss.
  > Numerous gardens comprises the castle.

Comment: Could you maybe add a little more context, on *when* it is separable and *when not*?

Comment: @Dbugger done :)

Comment: Was mir allerdings noch fehlt: 'er umfasst ihre Taille' passt nicht in das Schema oben rein. Hat jemand eine Idee wie man das erklären könnte?

Comment: @npe: Vielleicht hilft unterscheiden der Idee von "etwas von ringsumher anfassen" (die Taille, aber vor allem im übertragenen Sinn -> untrennbar), und "neu fassen/anfassen, die Stelle ändern" (-> trennbar).

Answer (score 1):

Der Unterschied liegt darin, ob ein Zustand oder eine Tätigkeit ausgedrückt wird. 
Geht es um das Greifen eines Spaten ist das Verb teilbar. Informationen zu umfassen ist dagegen ein Zustand; hier ist es nicht teilbar.

Comment: Auch das nicht teilbare _umfassen_ kann eine Tätigkeit ausdrücken: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/umfassen_beinhalten_einkreisen#Bedeutung1